# Docking framework for Eclipse Forms/SWT

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, portlet, docking

I have a few composites in an Eclipse editor, and the user would like to resize, maximize, restore, and move those composites around in the editor, as if each of those was a portlet.

Is there a toolkit for doing this, or is it something that I'll have to build myself from basic facilities like DnD and SashForms?

Thank you.

Pradyumna

Answer (score 2):

There is [Eclipse RCP](http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/Rich_Client_Platform): you can build your own application similar to Eclipse IDE.

Look at this tutorial too: [Create your first RCP application](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseRCP/article.html#firstrcp)

Comment: I do have an RCP application, and I have my own editor in it that responds to specific file types. What I'd like to do is have dockable, movable, resizable composites within (inside of) my editor in my RCP app.